# Show all data when page loads in Laravel + Vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-routing

Currently I'm Learning vue with laravel. I am making simple todo site. I am doing all stuff in `welcome.blade.php`. I am abel to store todos, but I am not able to view all todos.
Here is, what i tried

welcome.blade.php

```
 <div class="card-body">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" @click.prevent="createTodo()" value="Create">
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-10" v-model="todo.taskName">
            </div>
       </div>
       <hr>
       <div class="content">
             @{{ todo }}
       </div>
</div>
```

vue code

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#todo',
    data: {
        todo: {
            taskName: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createTodo: function createTodo() {
            var _this = this;
            var input = this.todo;
            axios.post('/create-todo', input).then(function (response) {
                _this.todo = {'taskName': ''};
                _this.getVueItems();
            });
        },
        getData: function getData(){
            axios.get('/').then(function (response) {
                this.todo = response.data;
            })
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getData();
    }
});
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('create-todo', 'TodoController@store');
```

I confused that how to return data. Because `/` route directly returns view.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add another route like :

```
 Route::get('get-todos', 'TodoController@index');
```

and in your vue :

```
 axios.get('/get-todos').then(function (response) {
            this.todo = response.data;
        })
```

your controller should be like :

```
       public function index(){
               return Todo::all();
        }
```

if you want to use the same url try this :

```
 Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
          if($request->ajax()){
             return Todo::all(); 
          } else{
             return view('welcome');
           } 
  });
```

Comment: thanks.I thought about that, but i want show that data on same page with same URL. Is that possible??

Comment: you should also add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and `use App\Todo;` in the top of your `web.php` file

Comment: try to replace `function (response) ` by `(response)=>` to avoid some issues

Comment: thank you, it works. but it works with this `mounted: function () {
        axios.get('/').then((response) => {
            this.todo = response.data;
            console.log(this.todo)
        })
    }` not with this `mounted: function () {
        this.getData();
    }` why?? could you please explain

Comment: ah yes, the error is here `getData: function getData(){ ..` it should be like `getData: function(){ ...` or `getData(){ ...`, the same thing for ` createTodo`

Comment: `methods: {
        createTodo() {
            var _this = this;
            var input = this.todos;
            axios.post('/create-todo', input).then(function (response) {
                    _this.todos.taskName = {'taskName': ''};
                })
        },
        getData() {
            axios.get('../').then((response) => {
                var _this = this;
                _this.todos = response.data;
            })
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getData();
    }` after this I can show data but not able to store data.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use VueJS you are using a front-end tool. This front-end tool will get the data from a "backend" part. You need to return data and not the HTML (unless you have a specific reason to do so)

Returning the data:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Todo::all();
});
```

At Vue:

```
 axios.get('/').then(response => {
   this.todo = response.data;
 })
```

Note the `response => {...}`. If you don't use ECMA6 notation `this` will refer to the function itself and not to the instance of Vue.

Since you are a beginner I highly advise you to check this out https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/

This tutorial will help you understand (see) the data returned and understand what is going on "under the hood"

**EDIT**

Also elaborating a little bit more: you are returning a collection which you will have to loop through. Otherwise you will be showing the `json` object

Comment: thanks, but it directly shows all data. It does not show html content

Comment: @MaulikShah that's exactly the behaviour expected. VueJS (axios) is expected to get **data** and not HTML content

Comment: but I also want to show that data in well format means in html tags

Answer (score 0):

From backend you need to pass data and in front you need to fetch data.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Todo::all();
});
```

At Vue:

```
axios.get('/').then(response => {
   this.todo = response.data;
 })
```